# Issue on Setting Limit for jQuery UI Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/VnQLJ/) and let me know why I am not able to set the limit boundaries for the Draggable div?

```
<div id="borders">
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag Mw In Yellow</p>
    </div>
</div> 

<script>
 $(function () {
     $("#draggable").draggable({
         containment: $(this).parent()
     });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(function () {
     $("#draggable").draggable({
         containment: "parent"
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$(this).parent()
```

by:

```
$("#borders")
```

That should do the trick.